# Angular. Validando formularios con FormGroup ¿No puedo preestablecer el mensaje en caso de fallo en el controlador del componente?

Tags: angular, formularios, validación, angular5, angular7

sigo con los formularios y le voy pillando el truquillo, me quedo con los **formsGroup** porque me parecen el que mejor encapsula y modulariza para lo que estoy llevando a cabo. Dicho esto, estoy creando **validaciones para mi formgroup que estan en la clase `Validator`** y tambien otras que he **customizado**.

Aqui os dejo mi controlador del formulario de registro:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css'],
})

export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  registerForm: FormGroup;


  constructor(
    public fb:FormBuilder
  ) {
      this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
        name:['',[Validators.required]],
        email:['',[Validators.required,Validators.email,Validators.pattern('"^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\\\.[a-z]{2,4}$"')]],
        password:['',[Validators.required]],
        repeat_password:['',[Validators.required]],
      },{
        validators:[this.checkPasswords,this.checkNameAndEmailMustBeEquals]
      });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  register() {
    // console.log(this.registerForm.value);
    // console.log(this.registerForm.controls);
    console.log(this.registerForm);
  }

  /**
   * CUSTOM VALIDATIONS
   */

  checkPasswords(form: FormGroup){
    const password = form.get('password').value;
    const repeatPassword = form.get('repeat_password').value;

    return password === repeatPassword ? null: {notSame:true};
  }

  checkNameAndEmailMustBeEquals(form:FormGroup){
      const name = form.get('name').value;
      const email = form.get('email').value;

      let strEmail = email.substring(0, email.lastIndexOf("@"));;

      return strEmail === name ? null : {notSame:true};
  }

}
```

Pero ahora quiero resolver el siguiente problema, **como intension es desacoplar de la vista casi todas las directivas ngIf y eso par alas validaciones** ya no quiero tener que decir en ellas :

> Si el campo name es requerido y no esta escrito (despues de haber pinchado en el) hardcodeo el error debajo del correspondiente input.

Ej:

```
 <div *ngIf="!first.valid && (first.dirty || first.touched)">
     <small class="text-danger font-weight-bold" *ngIf="first.errors.required">Campo obligatorio</small>
     <small class="text-danger font-weight-bold" *ngIf="first.errors.minlength">Longitud minima: 3 caracteres</small>
     <small class="text-danger font-weight-bold" *ngIf="first.errors.maxlength">Longitud maxima: 10 caracteres</small>
 </div>
```

Quiero pasar de hacer eso pues me resulta una forma de ensuciar la vista del componente mas de la cuenta.
¿No podria, junto a las validaciones (tanto de la clase Validator como las customizadas que tengo abajo)  poner  un mensaje en **string** que se displayearia por cada validacion fallida dentro de cada control del formulario? Poco un pseudocodigo de lo que me refiero:

Tengo esta validacion actualmente:

```
  this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
    name:['',[Validators.required]],
    email:['',[Validators.required,Validators.email,Validators.pattern('"^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\\\.[a-z]{2,4}$"')]],
    password:['',[Validators.required]],
    repeat_password:['',[Validators.required]],
  },{
    validators:[this.checkPasswords,this.checkNameAndEmailMustBeEquals]
  });
```

Pues poner por ejemplo, **en el caso de que el name, que esta requerido, no se haya puesto**:

```
 name:['',[Validators.required: 'Oye, que aqui dice que el name debe ser requerido'
        Validators.minLength(3),'Caracteres min: 3'
  ]],
```

Y asi con todo.

Y ya en la vista poner :

> Si name.validacionMinLengthFalla => name.validacionMin.mensaje

Espero que se me entienda, pero me parece una forma espectacular de modularizarlo, pero no he encontrado como hacerlo, no se si es que no es buena idea por x motivos o algo, espero me puedan ayudar. Muchas gracias, de verdad.

Comment: No hay nada así en Angular nativo, ya que tendrías que definir cómo quieres mostrar los inputs y los mensajes de error. Angular en ese sentido te da total libertad, pero sí puedes hacerlo usando por ejemplo **angular material**: https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#changing-when-error-messages-are-shown

Comment: @PabloLozano entonces por un lado empleo la logica de validacion y en la vista debo hacer manualmente cada mensaje de cada tipo de error en el caso de que falle ese tipo, no es asi ? Es la forma en la que angular lo contempla?

Comment: podrías crear una funcionalidad para comprobar la validación y devolver el mensaje de error, simplificando el template

Comment: Puedes crear un componente dónde guardes toda la lógica de la validación. Le pasas el formControl y obtienes todos los datos para mostrar el error.

Comment: @PabloLozano de acuerdo, muchas gracias. Me da la sensacion que esta 'bien visto' el hacer los if en la vista como me temia, y que se suele hacer. No es asi ? Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo que puedes hacer, es crear todas tus validaciones de manera "custom". Es decir, tendrías que implementar tu propio `[required, email, etc...]`, y así devolver lo que mas te acomode. Te dejo un ejemplo.

En este validador, vamos a evaluar nuestro `control.dirty & control.touched` para ahorrar código en el html. Así mismo podemos devolver propiedades extra para saber que error especifico sucede además regresamos nuestro mensaje "custom".

> Edit: mejor aún podemos enviar el mensaje parametrizado.

```
export function requiredValidator(message: string): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
    const value: string = control.value;
    const isNull = value == null;
    const isEmpty = /\s/g.test(value);
    const isLengthZero = value.trim().length == 0;
    const required =
      isNull || isEmpty || (isLengthZero && (control.dirty || control.touched));
    return required
      ? {
          required: {
            message: message,
            isNull,
            isEmpty,
            isLengthZero
          }
        }
      : null;
  };
}
```

Lo agregamos a nuestro formulario.

```
  this.myForm = fb.group({
      myField: ["", [requiredValidator("El nombre es requerido")]]
    });
```

Ya en nuestro html solo verificamos si el control contiene errores. De ser así obtenemos el mensaje de el validador.

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <input id="myField" type="text" formControlName="myField">
    <!-- Si el control contiene errores, los mostramos -->
    <span *ngIf="myForm.get('myField').errors">
      {{myForm.get('myField').errors.required.message}}
    </span>
 <!-- Podemos ver el objeto en caso de error:  { "required": { "message": "El nombre es requerido", "isNull": false, "isEmpty": false, "isLengthZero": true } }-->
 {{myForm.get('myField').errors | json}}
</form>
```

Comment: De acuerdo, me da la sensacion de que no esta tan mal visto hacer los if de validacion hardcodeados en angular no se porque. ¿Me equivoco? . Muchas gracias por tu aporte de verdad.